# How to get records from two tables in sql

Tags: sql

i have two DB tables STUDENT and FEES. Expected result is to get all record from table for particular month(date) with sum of amount in that month from FEES table and same id record from STUDENT table

## STUDENT

[image]

## FEES

[image]

**Expected result  (for particular date according to DATE cloumn in FEE table 
 ex : 02-2019 **

```
ID     NAME     ADDRESS     AMOUNT
-----------------------------------
S1     abc       ind        600
S2     pqr       ind        100
```

Comment: Date and Join date store in which format in sql like date or datetime

Comment: HyperSQL Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need results for a certain date, you don't need to group by date only by student:

```
select s.id, s.name, s.address, sum(f.amount) amount
from student s left join fees f 
on f.id = s.id
where f.date = '02-2019'
group by s.id, s.name, s.address;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8d2DeqHShfLiCyXnxBffXX/0).
Results:

```
| id  | name | address | amount |
| --- | ---- | ------- | ------ |
| S1  | abc  | ind     | 600    |
| S2  | pqr  | ind     | 100    |
```

In your expected results the amount for `id='S2'` and `date = '02-2019'` should be `100`, right?

Comment: Yes, amount for id='S2' and date = '02-2019' should be 100, question has been corrected.

Comment: I am using Hyper SQL database

Comment: The code in my answer works in any known dbms, I don't know about Hyper.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`INNER JOIN`**.

**Query**

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.address, sum(t2.amount) as amount
from student as t1
join fess as t2
on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.id, t1.name, t1.address;
```

Comment: this query showing all records, but in my case records should be month wise (according to DATE column in FEES table). Thanks..